# How to get the prompt text color of JavaFX textfiled

Tags: javafx

I need to use the default textfield prompt text color as the text color of a label. I can set the prompt text color using "-fx-prompt-text-fill" property, the problem is I couldn't find the "-fx-prompt-text-fill" property from the textfiled style class (.text-field, .text-input). I tried to use "getCssMetaData()" method of a textfield and the returned list doesn't include "-fx-prompt-text-fill".

Comment: I'm not sure how to get it programmatically, but it's defined in modena.css as `derive(-fx-control-inner-background, -30%)`

Comment: Hi James_D, thank you very much.